# Pronunciation of 'cos' (as in the mathematical term)

Tags: pronunciation, american-english, british-english, abbreviations

What is the correct pronunciation for the mathematical abbreviation 'cos' when it is *not* pronounced in its complete form 'cosine'? I pronounce it as 'k-aw-ss', but a couple of Canadian friends I have pronounce it as 'k-oh-s' (like the adjective 'close'). I tried looking up dictionaries but none that I came across list the IPA / phonetic pronunciation for the mathematical abbreviation.

(I think the former is the British English pronunciation, and the latter is the American English / Canadian English pronunciation.)

Comment: Another way of putting what my Canadian friends are pronouncing the term as would be 'cosine' with the 'ine' chopped off, as Stan Rogers mentioned in his answer below.

Comment: Another (possibly) interesting variation in pronunciation - for 'sinh' (hyperbolic sine, I pronounce it like 'shine' while my Canadian friends pronounce it like 'cinch'. And so on for other hyperbolic maths abbreviations. This one is [documented in the OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/180193).

Comment: I like cinch for sinh, and kosh for cosh. By the way, how do you pronounce tan? Tangent or tangens? In Russian, it is tangens.

Comment: @timur In its abbreviated form, I pronounce tan just like that - as in 'sun tan'. Otherwise, I pronounce it as 'tangent'.

Comment: @Ankur What about tanh?

Comment: @timur 't-han'. Like tan, but expelling air after the 't'.

Comment: Well, pronunciations of shortened forms don't depend on those of originals: for instance, prof vs professor. The pronunciation of "Cos" falls in the CLOTH lexical set: so pick the appropriate vowel for CLOTH in your dialect.

Comment: @timur: I've heard *sinh,* *cosh*, and *tanh* pronounced *sinsh*, *cosh* and *tansh* (I'm not sure whether the consonant at the end of *sinh* and *tanh* is *sh* or *ch*, but they sound nearly the same in AmE; this is the same phenomenon—epenthesis—that makes *prince* sound like *prints*).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In England everybody I know pronounces this so that it rhymes with "because".

Comment: This is what I found at my university (Surrey) too.

Comment: Or like Bill Cosby :)

Comment: There are other slightly alien words where UK English naturalises an <o> to /ɒ/ (as in UK 'cot') but N.Am English prefers an /oʊ/ (as in 'coat'). Examples that occur to me are 'kudos' and other Greek words in '-os', but I'm sure there are others with a different final consonant.

Comment: @Colin I think your comment comes quite close to the answer I was looking for; as in, the origin of the different pronunciations.

Comment: @Benjol The vowels in *Cosby* and *because* don’t sound at all alike.

Comment: But how do you pronounce 'because'? The  'au' can be like the 'o' in 'pot' or the 'ou' in cousin or 'or' as in 'born',  @tchrist They do to me!

Answer (score 13):

In speaking, I'd never use either of those pronunciations. "cos" means "cosine" -- say "cosine". Therefore I'd pronounce it "co-sign" ;)

Comment: It's like asking how to pronounce "Mr".  It's pronouced as the word it is, even if it is shortened.

Comment: 'Mr' was originally the abbreviation for *Magister* or Master (rather like Dr).  It's now its own word, with irregular pronunciation.

Comment: Yes, even when written "cos", pronounce "cosine".

Comment: And you pronounce "log" as "logarithm"?

Comment: @David: Yes. Although that is more likely to be pronounced as an abbreviation because 1. log is just a word, so an unambiguous pronunciation exists for it, and 2. it shortens 4 syllables to 1, whereas cosine to cos at most shortens 2 syllables to 1.

Comment: @David: And while we're at it yes, I would pronounce "ln" as "natural logarithm"

Comment: @BillyONeal Do you use these much? I work with log(arithm)s pretty frequently and it'd be a real drag to say "natural logarithm of *x*" however many times a day. (In my case, the base of the log is usually either implied by the context or just plain doesn't matter, so I can usually just say "log" for any logarithm without ambiguity.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby I would say "natural log" or simply "ln" (pronouncing the letters individually) because everyone whom I'd say that to would understand.

Comment: @SkeletonBow I certainly wouldn't say "ell en", since then both "the logarithm of x" and "L times n times x" would be pronounced "ell en ex".

Comment: That's true, but most of the time my audience would understand that I was talking about the natural logarithm from context. Where it could be ambiguous, however, I would definitely say "natural log."

Comment: I have a degree in Maths from an English University and years teaching Maths in school. We would almost always abbreviate in speech, except for sine. We would say log for any type of log provided it was clear which in the context but it was almost always natural in maths. They use logs base 10 in chemistry (e.g. pH). Mathematicians largely gave up logs base 10 when calculators were invented and we stopped using log tables for doing calculations. The pronunciation of sinh etc. was discussed and it was agreed that any valid attempt (including all the ones mentioned here) was OK.

Answer (score 11):

Well, I'm Canadian, and I was always taught (and taught, myself, when I was teaching) what would be rendered koʊs in the IPA (hard *c*, long *o*, hard *s*) -- exactly like "cosine" with the "ine" left off.

Comment: +1 American here, and I've only ever heard this version [koʊs, kəʊs].

Comment: Thanks -- I just noticed I missed pasting in the upside-down omega dealie (obviously, I have all of these glyphs on tap, but I can't get at them directly on this <expressive glyphs missing> machine -- it was configured for Chinese and Hebrew originally, and I haven't been able to exorcise all of the weirdness yet).

Comment: I added a comment to the question on the difference in pronunciation of hyperbolic trig abbreviations. Maybe there's a similar difference for cos?

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, my maths teacher says `cos` like *coz* with a 'z' sound at the end, as opposed to `cosine` which he says *co*, long o, `sine` as in *sign* (s-i-y-n).

**N.B.** `tan` is just as is sounds, with the 'a' short.

Comment: On those rare occasions when I needed to refer to hyperbolic functions, I  would pronounce "sinh" as "sin-huh", "tanh" as "tan-huh" and "cosh" to rhyme with "posh" or "gosh".  (The "-huh" would be more like blowing air out the nose than a pronounced word.)  I would also refer to a natural logarithm as "linn"....and sometimes a factorial (e.g., n!) as "N", loud and emphasized.  But these were all facetious; I would normally use the full names: hyperbolic [function], natural log[arithm], factorial, etc.